# Cannot Convert Type System.Collection.Generic.List<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to use generics to reduce my codebase, but ran into this situation.  I can't seem to successfully create a google query that expresses what I am trying to do.

In essence I am passing in a Generic to make a `List<T>` and then pass that `List<T>` into a function that requires a `List<SpecificClass>`

My JSONUser class

```
    public class JSONUser
    {
        public string DocumentId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "UserName", Required = Required.Always)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FirstName", Required = Required.AllowNull)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "LastName", Required = Required.AllowNull)]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
    }
```

Assume there is a class JSONCompany with company like fields.

Main Code:

```
static void CollectUserData()
{
     boolean j = GetJSON<JSONUser>();
     boolean k = GetJSON<JSONCompany>();
     ...
}

static boolean GetJSON<T>()
{
   ...
   // Get the JSON in a List
   List<T> oJSON = CallRest<T>();

   // Now depending on the type passed in, call a different
   // Process Function which expects a List<JSONUser> or
   // List<JSONCompany> parameter

   if (typeof(T) == typeof(JSONUser))
   {
       boolean result = ProcessUser(oJSON);
       ...
   }
   else if (typeof(T) == typeof(JSONCompany))
   {
       boolean result = ProcessCompany(oJSON);
       ...
   }
...
}

public boolean ProcessUser(List<JSONUser> JSONList)
{
    ...
}

public boolean ProcessCompany(List<JSONCompany> JSONList)
{
    ...
}
```

Everything is good until I call the `ProcessUser(oJSON);`

It says there is no method to accept the Generic.  When I try to cast it, it says

> Cannot Covert Type `System.Collection.Generic.List<T>` to `System.Collection.Generic.List<JSONUser>`

Hopefully this is clear.

Comment: If you only support two types you should create separate overloads rather than use generics. Otherwise pass the process function as a parameter i.e. `GetJSON<T>(Func<List<T>, bool> p)`

Comment: I have 5 types (for now).  I'll try the passing a function.  That might work well.  The overload may not be efficient either, there is more code not shown that uses the generic class.  It might be almost as easy to just create 5 different functions.

Comment: @Lee : It won't let me pass a function.  The non-generic method ProcessUser(System.Collection.Generic.List<JSONUser>) cannot be used with type arguments.

Comment: I'm suggesting you pass the process function as a parameter e.g. `GetJSON(ProcessUser)`. If you need to provide type parameters then it would be `GetJSON<JSONUser>(ProcessUser)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ProcessUser` et al does not *require* a list and can work with just an `IEnumerable<T>` then you can simplify it a bit:

```
public boolean ProcessUser(IEnumerable<JSONUser> JSONList)
{
    ...
}

public boolean ProcessCompany(IEnumerable<JSONCompany> JSONList)
{
    ...
}
```

Then just call it with:

```
boolean result = ProcessUser(oJSON.Cast<JSONUser>());
```

otherwise you *could* create a new list:

```
boolean result = ProcessUser(oJSON.Cast<JSONUser>().ToList());
```

which may be fine if you're just iteerating/modifying the *objects* in the list and not the list itself. (adding/removing/sorting/etc.)

Comment: Ahh, boolean result = ProcessUser(oJSON.Cast<JSONUser>());  The () was missing. or-- ProcessUser(oJSON.Cast<JSONCompany>().ToList());  If you can update your code example, I'll mark this as answer!

Comment: @ChristenDen Added the missing parens.

Answer (score 1):

As OP has indicated that the Process functions need to operate on the lists, here is a second answer to complement [my first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32100714/50356).  Based on feedback from OP, this assumes that the purpose of ProcessUser/ProcessCompany was really meant to bulk-upload the list of users/companies to a database, which I will assume to be SQL.  In this case, JSONUser and JSONCompany (and his other classes) would likely require different SQL calls to function correctly.

Thus, this code demonstrates iterating over the generic list, still using Interface on the base class to define how that object gets written to the database, and yet still not relying on typeof(T).

```
public interface IInsertToSql
{
    void InsertToSql(SqlCommand cmd);
}

public class JSONUser : IInsertToSql
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public void InsertToSql(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_insertJsonUser";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jsonUserId", UserID);
        // More parameters
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

public class JSONCompany : IInsertToSql
{
    public string CompanyID { get; set; }
    public void InsertToSql(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_insertJsonCompany";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jsonCompanyId", CompanyID);
        // More parameters....
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

void Main()
{
    List<JSONUser> users = GetJSON<JSONUser>();
    List<JSONCompany> companies = GetJSON<JSONCompany>();
    BulkUpload(users);
    BulkUpload(companies);
}

static void BulkUpload<T>(List<T> list)
    where T: IInsertToSql
{
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
    {
        conn.Open();
        foreach(T t in list)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) t.InsertToSql(cmd);
        }
    }
}

static List<T> GetJSON<T>()
{
    // OP's code to get the list of items, instead of...
    return new List<T>();
}
```

Comment: I must admit i really like the style, so thank-you. What I do is iterate through the list and populate a data-table which is passed as a parameter to the sql call.  I can definitely see how I can adapt this to achieve what I am trying to do.  I am however having to give the answer to D Stanley because it achieves the result with the intent of the original request.

Answer (score 0):

Having specific functions to do specific things to specific generic types is generally against the design idea of generics.  If you are checking typeof(T) then this is a good indicator (but not necessarily a perfect one) that there's probably a better design.

There are several ways to accomplish what I *think* you are trying to do...  here's one example to get your brain moving in the right direction:

If ProcessUser and ProcessCompany both operate on a single object (that is, the list items, as opposed to the list itself), as the method names seem to imply, then you could make both JSONUser and JSONCompany inherit from an interface, say ICanProcess that has a method Process() that returns a bool.  Then you can say:

```
interface ICanProcess
{
    bool Process();
}
class JSONUser : ICanProcess
{
    // implement Process for this object
}
static bool GetJSON<T>()
    where T: ICanProcess
{
    ...
    bool result = true;
    foreach(T it in oJSON)
    {
        // I assume the result should be AND of all items process result
        result = result && it.Process();  
    }
}
```

Comment: @MichaelBay It took me about 10 re-reads to understand what you mean, but I love the idea.  I will hack away at it.  If I understand it right, I'll need a Process() function in the classes JSONUser and JSONCompany et al...

Comment: @MichaelBay I quickly discovered that I do need to work on the list and not just the list items (Doing a batch upload into a database).  But I do like the thought process otherwise.  I'll think more about this.

Comment: So I think maybe you have confused us....   What do ProcessUser and ProcessCompany actually do?  Do they actually perform the batch upload?  If that's true, then I would have expected them to be called something more like UploadUserList and UploadCompanyList.  Pending your response, I might be able to provide a revised/better answer.

Comment: Based on your feedback and a few more assumptions, I've provided a second answer that might be closer to your situation, in which the list is meant to be bulk uploaded.  That answer also avoids the use of typeof(T), which should be your ultimate goal.